# If $(X_i)$ are independent and $\tau_i=\inf\{k >\tau_{i-1}\mid X_k=1\}$ why $(\tau_i-\tau_{i-1})$ are independents

Tags: probability

Let $(X_i)$ independent s.t. $\mathbb P=\{X_i=0\}=p$ and $\mathbb P\{X_i=1\}=1-p$. Let $\tau_0=0$ and set $$\tau_i=\inf\{k>\tau_{i-1}\mid X_k=1\}.$$ Set $$T_i=\tau_{i}-\tau_{i-1}.$$

I want to prove that $(T_i)_i$ are independents.

> **proposition** I know that if $U_1,...,U_n$ and $V_1,...,V_m$ are independents, then so are $f(U_1,...,U_n)$ and $g(V_1,...,V_m)$ or equivalently that $\sigma (U_1,...,U_n)$ and $\sigma (V_1,...,V_m)$ are independent.

The fact that the $(T_i)$ are independent looks quite natural, but I would like to avoid to prove that $$\mathbb P\{T_1=k_1,T_2=k_2,...,T_{m}=k_m\}=\mathbb P\{T_1=k_1\}...\mathbb P\{T_m=k_m\}.$$

**Q1)** Is there a way to use my proposition ? Something as $T_1$ is $\sigma (X_1,...,X_{\tau_1})$ measurable, $T_2$ is $\sigma (X_{\tau_1+1},...,X_{\tau_2})$ measurable... and conclude ?

**Q2)** Does $\sigma (X_1,...,X_{\tau_k})$ really make sense ? I don't have the impression.

**Q3)** Is there a way to prove that the $T_i$ are identically distributed ? It looks very natural, but a bit long to prove. Maybe there is a trick ?

**Q4)** I know that it's not enough to prove that a collection $\{A_i\}_i$ is pairwise independent to prove that the collection is independent, but in this case, wouldn't it be sufficient to prove that $T_i,T_j$ are independent to prove that any finite vector of $T_i$ are independent ?

Comment: Q4: Since you know this is not sufficient in general, why would you think it would be sufficient in this case?

Comment: @NateEldredge: for me it shouldn't be, but in the exercise I had, the teacher says for all these questions that "we clearly see that...", but when I try to make things rigorously, it doesn't looks obvious, and rather very long to prove... Even if I agree that all the answer make sense...

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define a $\sigma$-field associated with $\tau_i$. Let $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Then we define
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\tau_i}:=\{A\in \mathcal{F}_{\infty}:A\cap \{\tau_i=n\}\in \mathcal{F}_n \text{ for all }n\}.
$$
Note that $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_i}$ is a $\sigma$-field and since $\tau_{i-1}\le \tau_i$, one has $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_{i-1}}\subset \mathcal{F}_{\tau_i}$.

Let $f_i(x):=1\{T_i=x\}$ with $\tau_0\equiv 0$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)\right]&=\mathsf{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(x_i)\mathsf{E}[f_n(x_n)\mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_{n-1}}]\right]=\mathsf{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_i(x_i)\right]\mathsf{E}f_1(x_n) \\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathsf{E}f_1(x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i-1}(1-p).
\end{align}

It remains to justify the second equality. Let $A\in \mathcal{F}_{\tau_{i-1}}$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[f_i(x);A\cap \{\tau_{i-1}<\infty\}]&=\sum_{m\ge 1}\mathsf{E}[f_i(x);A\cap \{\tau_{i-1}=m\}] \\
&=\sum_{m\ge 1}\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[1\{X_{m+1}=0,X_{m+2}=0,\ldots,X_{m+x}=1\}\mid \mathcal{F}_m]; \\
&\qquad\qquad A\cap \{\tau_{i-1}=m\}] \\[10pt]
&=\sum_{m\ge 1}\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f_1(x)];A\cap \{\tau_{i-1}=m\}] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[f_1(x)];A\cap \{\tau_{i-1}<\infty\}].
\end{align}

The last equation shows that $\mathsf{E}[f_i(x)\mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_{i-1}}]=\mathsf{E}f_1(x)$ a.s. on $\{\tau_{i-1}<\infty\}$. However, it is easy to see that $\mathsf{P}(\tau_i<\infty)=1$ for any $i\ge 1$. Therefore, $\mathsf{E}f_i(x)=\mathsf{E}f_1(x)=p^{x-1}(1-p)$.

Comment: Thank you. Several question : I'm not really sure what you tried to prove. It looks very complicate for an exercise that shouldn't be so difficult. Also, what do you mean by : we prove that $E[f_i(x)\mid \mathcal F_{\tau_i}]=Ef_1(x)$ a.s. on $\{\tau_i<\infty \}$ ? Also, the notation $\mathbb E[f_i(x)\mid \mathcal F_{\tau_i}]$ looks strange is $f_i(x)$ really an random variable ?

Comment: $f_i(x)=1\{\tau_i-\tau_{i-1}=x\}$. It's an r.v. because $\tau_i$'s are random.

Comment: I proved that
$$
\mathbb P\{T_1=k_1,T_2=k_2,...,T_{m}=k_m\}=\mathbb P\{T_1=k_1\}...\mathbb P\{T_m=k_m\}.
$$
for any $k_1,\ldots,k_m$.